# Conversion failed converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I'm writing a dynamic query and I need to cast a datetime variable as a time variable

```
DECLARE @pdatetime_GarageOpenFrom DATETIME = '2013-07-25 08:00:00'

declare  @str_SQLCount2 varchar(max)
set @str_SQLCount2 = 'select (CONVERT(CHAR(10), @pdatetime_GarageOpenFrom, 111)'
print(@str_SQLCount2)
exec(@str_SQLCount2)
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a bracket at the end of the SELECT query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course this generates an error.  The variable `@pdatetime_GarageOpenFrom` is not known in the context of the exec statement.

You basically have two options.  Either declare the variable in the sql string or use `sp_executesql()`.

```
declare  @str_SQLCount2 varchar(max)
set @str_SQLCount2 = '
DECLARE @pdatetime_GarageOpenFrom DATETIME = ''2013-07-25 08:00:00''
select CONVERT(CHAR(10), @pdatetime_GarageOpenFrom, 111)'
print(@str_SQLCount2)
exec(@str_SQLCount2)
```

The preferred method is `sp_execute_sql` with your original string:

```
DECLARE @pdatetime_GarageOpenFrom DATETIME = '2013-07-25 08:00:00'

declare  @str_SQLCount2 varchar(max);
set @str_SQLCount2 = 'select CONVERT(CHAR(10), @pdatetime_GarageOpenFrom, 111)';
print(@str_SQLCount2);

exec sp_executesql @str_SQLCount2,
                   N'@pdatetime_GarageOpenFrom DATETIME',
                   @pdatetime_GarageOpenFrom = @pdatetime_GarageOpenFrom;
```

Comment: im my case i cant use

Comment: i usethis for call scalar function like this
FT_CalBusinessHours('+ISNULL('b.ModDate','b.CreateDate')+',GETDATE(),'+CAST(@pdatetime_GarageOpenFrom AS TIME)+')